# Is there a way to list all connections to socketserver in Python3?

Tags: sockets, python-3.x, socketserver

I'm wondering if there's a way to list or iterate through the sockets currently open with `socketserver`. Here's how it is basically structured:

```
class SSL_TCPServer(TCPServer)
    def __init__(self, private, public, server_address, RequestHandlerClass, certfile, keyfile, ssl_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1, bind_and_activate=True):
        TCPServer.__init__(self, server_address, RequestHandlerClass, bind_and_activate)
        foo()

class TestSSL(ThreadingMixIn, SSL_TCPServer):
    pass

class TestHandler(StreamRequestHandler):
    def handle(self):
        bar()

TestSSL(private, public, (HOST, PORT),TestHandler,"./crt.pem", "./key.pem").serve_forever()
```

I can handle multiple clients and deal with sockets on a per-person level. However, if I wanted to turn this into a more interactive chat-type socket, how can I iterate through the currently connected sockets and see which ones are available to talk to?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have a list of sockets, the easiest and most portable way is to *make* one. :-) Append the sockets that you create to a list; this can be a module level variable, or a class attribute.

Most operating systems allow you to get a list of open sockets. But how this is done differs significantly between operating systems;

On FreeBSD you can get the information from `sysctl` calls. On Linux you can find it in the `/proc` filesystem.

Comment: Thanks. I had originally tried using /proc/[pid]/net/tcp, but I figured there was an easier way to do it programattically. I do have an ID attribute for each ssl_wrap()'ed socket, so I can definitely do a dictionary there and interact with it that way, but it just seems inefficient to me. Perhaps not.